# Firebase Auth: The format of the phone number provided is incorrect

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement phone number authentication in my Flutter app using Firebase Auth. However, when I attempt to verify the phone number using the verifyPhoneNumber method provided by FirebaseAuth.instance, I keep receiving the following error:

```
flutter: +15555551234
flutter: sending otp to +15555551234
flutter: Auth failed: The format of the phone number provided is incorrect. Please enter the phone number in a format that can be parsed into E.164 format. E.164 phone numbers are written in the format [+][country code][subscriber number including area code].
```

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
Future verifyPhone({
  String? phoneNumber,
  required void Function(PhoneAuthCredential) verificationCompleted,
  required void Function(FirebaseAuthException) verificationFailed,
  required void Function(String, int?) codeSent,
  required void Function(String) codeAutoRetrievalTimeout,
  int? forceResendingToken,
}) async {
  debugPrint('sending otp to $phoneNumber');
  try {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
      verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
      codeSent: codeSent,
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout,
      forceResendingToken: forceResendingToken,
    );
  } catch (e) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

No matter how I format a US phone number, I keep getting the error mentioned above. Code works fine for country code +91.

Could someone please help me understand what I might be doing wrong? I'm already using E.164 formatting. Is +15555551234 not a valid number?

Answer (score 0):

For US numbers you must use a valid area code. ie.+16625551234. I had this same issue trying to use the 555 area code.